# How do I prevent \cellcolor from over effect of \hline

Tags: tables, formatting, color

I'm trying to add HTML code based color to my table, like so:

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{tabular}{ |>{\columncolor[HTML]{F2FAF8}}c| p{11cm} |}
    \hline
CELL 1 & CELL 2\\ \hline
CELL 1 & CELL 2\\ \hline
CELL 1 & CELL 2\\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
```

however, the cells seem to overflow on top of the \hline, like so:

[image: Bad table!]

How do I prevent this from happening?

*UPDATE* in response to comments:

I tried:

```
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{ |>{\columncolor[HTML]{F2FAF8}}c| p{11cm} |}
    \hline
CELL 1 & CELL 2\\ \hline
CELL 1 & CELL 2\\ \hline
CELL 1 & CELL 2\\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
```

no go:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't really happen (I claim:-) try zooming in or out in your pdf viewer. You could increase the length \arrayrulewidth to have slightly less fragile lines.

Comment: Seems to work fine when I compile with your minimal example.  Are there perhaps other packages you're loading which might be interacting here?

Comment: I'm generating pngs, not pdfs, with dvipng.

Comment: @A.Ellett I don't think so. My preamble consists of: \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I claim this is a problem with the dvi driver bleeding the coloured panels too far, but I see the same with `dvipng` You can compensate by over-printing an uncoloured table over the top so the rules are on top of the colour not adjacent.

Compare

[image]

and

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\def\foo#1{\begin{tabular}{ |>{#1}c| p{11cm} |}
    \hline
CELL 1 & CELL 2\\ \hline
CELL 1 & CELL 2\\ \hline
CELL 1 & CELL 2\\ \hline
 \end{tabular}}


\foo{\columncolor[HTML]{F2FAF8}}\llap{\foo{}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The text looks bolder though.

Comment: @Wok yes it would be better to arrange that the overprint version uses phantom for the text so just has the rules

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` has tools which has been designed to address that kind of problem. With that package, the rules won't seem to disappear in some PDF viewers at some levels of zoom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{F2FAF8}}cp{11cm}}[color-inside,hvlines]
CELL 1 & CELL 2\\ 
CELL 1 & CELL 2\\ 
CELL 1 & CELL 2\\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]