# \cellcolor removes \hline

Tags: tables, color

I have a table where I am filling some of the cells with a gray color. It works fine. The problems is however, that the horizontal lines of the table becomes gray too. How can I solve this so that the lines stays as Black lines and the cell color is gray?

Image of my problem:
[image]

A complete code example can be found online [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/542bf9654eb5b9c772559960) or in this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{slashbox,pict2e}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
    \hline\backslashbox{Enhed}{Interface} & ED    & DDG   & \textit{Server} \\
    \hline  ED      & \checkmark        & \checkmark        & {\cellcolor{Gray}} \\
    \hline DDG     & \checkmark        & {\cellcolor{Gray}}  & \checkmark \\
    \hline \textit{Server}  & {\cellcolor{Gray}}  & \checkmark        & {\cellcolor{Gray}}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Oversigt over interfaces mellem enhederne.}
\label{tab:interfacesMellemEnheder}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate(s): [Cell shading without removing lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25062/5764); [`\cellcolor` overwrites table lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65582/5764); [How do I prevent `\cellcolor` from over effect of `\hline`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114226/5764)

Comment: It's only a problem with the pdf viewer. Check with a large zoom. Normally there should be no problem with the printer.

Comment: also there should be no `{}` around `\cellcolor` (although it makes no difference here)

Comment: `slashbox` is a very old package, you might try `diagbox` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Bernard. I will have a look at diagbox :) If you put your answer as a solution I will mark it ;)

Comment: Beside the technical "fake" problem, the true problem  is the obsession to put as many rules as possible. My suggestion is use `booktabs`, not diagbox, one \toprule, one \cmidrule{2-4} for "Interface" in a multicolumn, a \midrule, a \bottomrule and ... and nothing else.

Comment: @Fran do you have an example of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can read in the comments there never was a problem with the tex code. The only problem was the pdf viewer. When zooming in the lines gets visible again. This will not be a problem when printing the page.

Comment: I currently have this exact issue and both Google Chrome and Adobe Acrobat display my PDF incorrectly. You can say "not a problem with tex code, only problem with pdf viewers", but if practically all viewers of my PDF are going to see it incorrectly, it does become my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 4.0 2020-05-08) gives a solution to that problem.

With `colortbl`, a `\hline` is drawn and, if there is a colored cell in the following row, the colored rectangle is drawn *after* the horizontal rule. Even if the position of the rule and of the colored rectangle are mathematically exact, almost all PDF viewers give priority to the colored rectangle (explicitly drawn after in the PDF): they consider that, at a low zoom level, the rules drawn before are only detail less important (that's why it's difficult to say that this is a 'issue' of the viewer).

With `nicematrix`, this problem is solved because all the rules are drawn *after* the colored rectangles (rows, columns, cells, etc.).

Moreover, `nicematrix` provides a command `\diagbox` and a key `hvlines` to draw all the rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{wl{2.2cm}ccc}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \cellcolor{lightgray}{2-4,3-3,4-2,4-4}
\Body
\rule[-3mm]{0pt}{9mm}
\diagbox{Enhed}{Interface} & ED    & DDG   & \textit{Server}  \\
  ED                       & \checkmark    & \checkmark     &  \\
 DDG                       & \checkmark    &                & \checkmark \\
 \textit{Server}           &               & \checkmark     & \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Oversigt over interfaces mellem enhederne.}
\label{tab:interfacesMellemEnheder}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: The same issue persists! At a certain zooming level, the separating line is not visible.

Comment: @MohamedAbdelhamid : It's difficult to answer without more information. If you want, send me a mail (you will find my address on the documentation of `nicematrix`) the MWE, the PDF viewer, the level of zoom, etc. and I will try to provide a precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is too long for a comment. As requested by FireFly3000, an example with `booktabs` with only a few rules:

[image: MWE]

In this type of table  `diagbox` have no utility, so you can put "Interface" in a multicolumn in a previous row, and left only "Enhed" in the cell, or if you prefer this label vertically centered, use the `multirow` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl, booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{Enhed} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Interface} \\
\cmidrule{2-4}
            & ED                &  DDG             & \textit{Server} \\
\midrule
ED               & \checkmark        & \checkmark       & \cellcolor{Gray} \\
DDG              & \checkmark        & \cellcolor{Gray} & \checkmark       \\
\textit{Server}  & \cellcolor{Gray}  & \checkmark       & \cellcolor{Gray} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Oversigt over interfaces mellem enhederne.}
\label{tab:interfacesMellemEnheder}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is just to increase the table linewidth. The PDF viewer will then no longer have the issue.

`\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt} %Increasing linewidth 
\begin{table} 
(...)
\end{table}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.4pt} %Back to default`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This is an issue with the pdf viewer, changing linewidth is not needed ...

Comment: Latex generated documents is supposed to Interface with PDF-Viewers, so I do not get this argument. If it is the norm for PDF-Viewers is to display Tables in this manner, then I would  argue that it effectively is a Latex-issue. And I provided one simple way to handle it. See discussion of "F. Pantigny", which it seems provided a nice solution to the problem without need of increasing the linewidth.

Comment: @Einar U: I agree with you and think that the problem can't be considered only as a 'issue of the viewer'.

Comment: It's certainly not just an "issue of the viewer", because I've printed the document and the lines were not there either. Also,  PDFs are thought to be both printed and read on screen, so what's the point if they do not show correctly on screen?